# Eliminar registros duplicados en SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM CLIENTES
```

Y este es mi resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito eliminar los duplicados y en el caso del `ID_CLIENTE` 7075593 que la fecha es diferente debo dejar la fecha mas antigua en este caso se tendría que eliminar el registro #9 ya que la fecha es mayor que la del registro #10

Comment: te vuelvo a aclarar lo de las fechas porque es super importante.. 06022019 es mayor que 31012019 en teoria, pero en la practica en el orden, te va 06022019 como menor.. porque lexicograficamente es menor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para esto nada mejor que agrupar los resultados (eso deja uno solo) y tomar la menor fecha de todas, que como es un numero tiene todavia menos problemas

```
Select territorial, id_cliente, min(fecha)
from CLIENTES
group by territorial, id_cliente
```

Con esto, estas diciendo que agrupe por el mismo territorial, y despues agrupe por id_cliente (que es lo que te deja una sola fila por cliente) y despues, solo te estas quedando con el minimo fecha, que como estan en ansi, pero al reves (cuando uno guarda fechas en ese formato, como un numero, que se llama ansi, se guardan en formato yyyymmdd, porque si no despues cuesta ordenarlas), con un min, obtenemos la mas chiquita..

Answer (score 0):

**Detalle de como eliminar registros duplicados de una tabla en SQL Server:**

1.- El primer paso es obtener el Id mas viejo por cliente duplicado con un Min sobre el Id del Cliente y agrupando por los campos de la tabla para obtener los duplicados.

2.- El segundo paso es realmente borrar los registros duplicados.

El Script en concreto es el siguiente:

```
  BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DELETE FROM [CLIENTES]
    WHERE ID_CLIENTE NOT IN
    (
        SELECT MIN(ID_CLIENTE )
        FROM [CLIENTES]
        GROUP BY CamposDeLaTabla
    )

  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

3.- Si todo esta bien comenta el código rollback y ponle COMMIT TRANSACTION

Saludos, Espero y sea de utilidad.